# Jquery Dropdown Search rails 2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How to make a selection(dropdown) search.I have 3 selection and when the user selects a dropdown the result div will reload to show results of the subjects.

```
Senario:

     select year | select semester | select course

    <div id="result">
     list of subjects base on the 3 selections
    </div>
```

Comment: @parasad has the general idea down. You need to look into Ajax (jQuery supports it very well) and understanding the relationship of MVC in Rails. Read up on those topics and I think it will greatly move you forward in your understanding of how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure abt the code below working on rails 2.3 but it works on rails 3

```
$("#third_select_box_id").change ->
  first_select_box_data = $("#first_select_box_id").val()
  second_select_box_data = $("#second_select_box_id").val()
  third_select_box_data = $("#third_select_box_id").val()
  #add code to check that the first n second dropdown list have some data that has been    selected
  if (the data has been selected in all dropdown lists then )
    $.ajax
      type: "GET"
      data: "year="+first_select_box_data+"&semester="+second_select_box_data+"&course="+third_select_box_data
      url:"/courses/get_results"
```

If u want to display the data even if the year or semester isnt selected, dont do the checking in above coffeescript. In routes

```
resources: courses do
  get 'get_results'
end
```

in courses controller

```
def get_results
  @results = #ur logic to collect all results based on received params. Handle the condition that year or semester isnt selected(if u want to)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}
  end
end
```

in get_results.js.haml

```
$("#result").html("#{escape_javascript(render :partial => 'results')}")
```

in _results.html.haml

```
#ur logic to display the @results
```

Do consider using datatables for listing as it will increase the performance.

Answer (score 0):

send a ajax and collect the search results. in search.js.haml, replace the div 'result' with a partial that will list the search results.

Comment: I would appreciate if you can give a little code :D and also I updated the post. I'm using rails 2.3 by the way.